# How to force mouse focus to a windows app

Tags: c++, windows, ogre3d

I am converting a game from the 1997 source and updating it to HD. It's all going well except for one niggling element. When I launch the game, the mouse does not have focus on the app. (it shows a blue circle spinning around). When I hit CTRL ALT DEL (to bring up the task manager menu) and then hit ESC. The mouse is now focused on the game and all it well!   It's been a while since I've programmed windows but this seems bizarre. If anyone has any ideas on how to get my game to get mouse focus out of the gate I would much appreciate it!  :)

Thanks

Comment: No one could begin to guess at the answer without further details.

Comment: Its a windows 8.1 standalone game app. The front end is based off the windows dialog box system. It is all 2D dialog box style. The main game is rendered in 3D using Ogre3D (which works great). I just have this one issue with the mouse focus. I have my window set up, it displaying everthing correctly (including animated elenents).It's just that the mouse doesnt get focus unless I CTRL ALT DEL and then ESC.

Comment: Written in C++ on VS2008